# Find the derivative of this function at a specific point

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

What is the derivative of $$f(t)= \frac{t^3 +2} t$$ at point $(-2,3)$.

Comment: Can you share your thoughts? Did you try the Quotient Rule? What have you tried?

Comment: If you split the fraction, you can apply old school power rule. Give it a try first...

Comment: Thanks , I think after that I plug in the x value, -2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets take the derivative of the function according to the definition so we have:

$$f'(-2)=\lim_{x\to -2}\frac{f(x)-f(-2)}{x-(-2)}$$ **if the limit exists**. So we should do: 
$$f'(-2)=\lim_{x\to -2}\frac{\frac{x^3 +2} x-3}{x+2}=\lim_{x\to -2}\frac{x^2-2x+1}{x}=-9/2$$

Comment: Nice work, Babak. I suspect this is what the OP needed! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Thank you dear friend. :-)

Comment: Do not worry. I too feel my contributions are small, but I do what I can, and am inspired by others like yourself! I'm not off to a good start this morning :-(

Comment: @amWhy: You have friends here instead. I believe it'll be changed positively. A good charming day ahead. :-)

Answer (score 1):

$$f(t)=t^2+\dfrac{2}{t}$$
so
$$f'(t)=2t-\dfrac{2}{t^2}$$
so
$$f'(-2)=2\cdot (-2)-\dfrac{2}{(-2)^2}=-4-\dfrac{1}{2}=-\dfrac{9}{2}$$